# Nez / Monogame : Can't click buttons but mouse actions are properly registering

Tags: java, monogame

So, I dont know if I am missing something but any way I work it or look into it I am unable to click on any buttons on the screens.

I made a dialog box with a button essentially as shown in the sample projects but when ever I try to click the button nothing happens at all.
I tried firing the onClick programmatically and it works fine, I also tested that the mouse inputs were being registered okay and they were.
I am at a total loss for any reason why this wouldnt work.

My class code is below:

```
public class Interactable : UICanvas
{

    public void interact()
    {
        var skin = Skin.createDefaultSkin();

        var table = stage.addElement(new Table());
        table.center();
        table.setFillParent(true);

        table.add(talk(this.entity.name, "Stay a while and glisten", "Bye!"));

    }


    public Dialog talk(string title, string messageText, string closeButtonText)
    {
        var skin = Skin.createDefaultSkin();

        var style = new WindowStyle
        {
            background = new PrimitiveDrawable(new Color(50, 50, 50)),
            //Dims the background
            stageBackground = new PrimitiveDrawable(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150))
        };

        var dialog = new Dialog(title, style);
        dialog.getTitleLabel().getStyle().background = new PrimitiveDrawable(new Color(55, 100, 100));
        dialog.pad(20, 5, 5, 5);
        dialog.addText(messageText);
        var exitButton = new TextButton(closeButtonText, skin);
        exitButton.onClicked += butt => dialog.hide();
        dialog.add(exitButton);


        return dialog;
    }


}
}
```

The `interact()` is called when running up to another entity and pressing "E".
Which causes everything to render properly but I can't click on the button.

Additionally:
When i try to view `exitButton` co-ordinates theyre always 0 no matter what although the dialog appears in the middle of the window

Monogame version: 3.7
Nez version: 0.9.2

UPDATE: 
So it seems like buttons are clickable but their click box is not even nearly aligning with where the buttons are truely rendered.

UPDATE2:
It seems that the issue is that where the button is being rendered and where the actual click box is are not the same.
I have Zoomed in the camera by 2 and the camera also follows my little character around. The dialog will then appear at the X,Y in relation to the current camera view but the actual click box appears at the X,Y in terms of the TiledMap (which is not always on screen).
Not too sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So! The issue I was having was I was using one renderer for the entire this (The RenderLayerRenderer.) What I have done to fix this is start another renderer (A ScreenSpaceRenderer). This allows me to use it to render UI and its XY variables do not change but are just static to the visual area.

So i ended up with two renders like so:

```
addRenderer(new RenderLayerRenderer(0,new int[] { (int)RenderLayerIds.First, (int)RenderLayerIds.Second, (int)RenderLayerIds.Third}));
addRenderer(new ScreenSpaceRenderer(1, new int[] { (int)RenderLayerIds.UILayer }));
```

Using the first for my game rendering and the bottom on just for HUD things!